Bootstrap, menu scrolls back to top after close menu
When I open my menu, and click on link, I scroll to down page with my menu, but when I close menu, I go back to the top of the page.
The scripts I have tried:
let y = window.scrollY;
let offcanvas = document.getElementById('offcanvasMenu');
offcanvas.addEventListener('hidden.bs.offcanvasMenu', (e) => {
   window.scrollTo(0, y);
});

and
var myOffcanvas = document.getElementById('offcanvasNav')
myOffcanvas.addEventListener('hide.bs.offcanvas', function (e) {
    console.log(e)
    //e.preventDefault()
    //e.stopPropagation()
})

but these scripts do not help me.
Code Snippet


<a class="bi bi-list offcanvas-icon" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" href="#offcanvasMenu" role="button" aria-controls="offcanvasMenu"></a>


<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" data-bs-scroll="true" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasMenu" aria-labelledby="offcanvasMenuLabel">
  <div class="offcanvas-header">
    <button type="button" class="btn-close ms-auto" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>

  <div class="offcanvas-body d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#contacts">Контакти</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>

<section class="contact-widget spad" id="contacts">lala </section>`

<!-- Bootstrap 5 + icons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>




Here is a workaround:
The thing is, on hide.bs.offcanvas, the scrolling (going to the nav) will start already. So you can put a code there to stay on that scroll position.
Your JS code should be like this:
    let myOffcanvas = document.getElementById('offcanvasMenu');

    myOffcanvas.addEventListener('hide.bs.offcanvas', function (e) {
        let currentScrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;

        setTimeout((() => {
            document.documentElement.scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop = currentScrollTop;
        }), 310);
    });

First, you get the current position before (while) it scrolls back to the origin (nav). Then after 310 ms, return immediately to the current position.
The 310 ms may vary. In my code, 300 works fine. Higher number will work also but you'll notice the bouncing of the page from the origin to current position. Lower number will likely fail.
Here is a working sample:


    let myOffcanvas = document.getElementById('offcanvasMenu');

    myOffcanvas.addEventListener('hide.bs.offcanvas', function (e) {
        let currentScrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;

        setTimeout((() => {
            document.documentElement.scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop = currentScrollTop;
        }), 310);
    });
<a class="bi bi-list offcanvas-icon" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" href="#offcanvasMenu" role="button" aria-controls="offcanvasMenu"></a>


<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" data-bs-scroll="true" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasMenu" aria-labelledby="offcanvasMenuLabel">
  <div class="offcanvas-header">
    <button type="button" class="btn-close ms-auto" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>

  <div class="offcanvas-body d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#contacts">Контакти</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>A
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>B
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>C
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>D
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>E
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>F
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>G
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>H
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<section class="contact-widget spad" id="contacts">Contact </section>

<!-- Bootstrap 5 + icons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>



Note that I added many <br> so you can see how it works.

Great Tnx, this code is work perfect for me!

Solved my problem.
